# Cq5/AEM Query Tool is not fetching results

Tags: sql, adobe, aem

[image]Query Tool in crxde lite page , is not fetching results.
I have passed the values as given in the screen shot in one instance its showing  results. In another instance its not showing results.

Comment: U r looking for content under geometrixx. R u sure both instances hv geometrixx installed?

Comment: yes Both the instance has geometrixx installed

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is kind of full text search. For the resource type the query is -

```
select * from [nt:base] where [sling:resourceType] = 'your resource Type here' and ISDESCENDANTNODE('your path here')
```

Comment: Yeah. I used similar kinda Query staement

Comment: In that case you can use query check tool in AEM to verify whats happening with your query.

Comment: Yeah i tried. Even the query tool is fetching 0 result